# Hide menu backend side for different roles/users

Tags: 7, routes

I'd like to hide some menu on the backend side /admin/structure/menu and make the hidden items to disappear of the navigation menu for a specific user/role.

I managed to hide the list of the menu visible in the page /admin/structure/menu but it's just the list which as been changed, meaning they can access by accessing to the url.

```
function module_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/devel']['page callback'] = 'module_change_devel';
    $items['admin/structure/menu']['page callback'] = 'module_change_menus';
}

function module_change_menus() {

    global $user;
    if(!in_array('administrator', $user->roles)){
        $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {menu_custom} 
            WHERE menu_name='menu-contact-us' 
            OR menu_name='menu-1' 
            OR menu_name = 'menu-3' 
            OR menu_name = 'menu-2' 
            ORDER BY title", 
            array(), 
            array('fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }
    else{
       $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {menu_custom} 
           ORDER BY title", 
           array(), 
           array('fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); 
    }
    $rows = array();
    $header = array(t('Title'), array('data' => t('Operations'), 'colspan' => '3'));
    foreach ($result as $menu) {
    $row = array(theme('menu_admin_overview', array('title' => $menu['title'], 'name' => $menu['menu_name'], 'description' => $menu['description'])));
    $row[] = array('data' => l(t('list links'), 'admin/structure/menu/manage/' . $menu['menu_name']));
    $row[] = array('data' => l(t('edit menu'), 'admin/structure/menu/manage/' . $menu['menu_name'] . '/edit'));
    $row[] = array('data' => l(t('add link'), 'admin/structure/menu/manage/' . $menu['menu_name'] . '/add'));
    $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));

}


function menu_change_devel() {

    global $user;
    if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles) == 1){
        $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/devel']['access arguments'] =  array('aminister users');
        return $items;
    }
}
```

But the function menu_change_devel which is supposed to give the access to admin/structure/menu/manage/devel for the user having the permission to aminister users doesn't seem to work :(

Any idea ?

Cheers

EDIT :
I found the solution

```
function MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {

    //deny the menu if they are not admin (if they don't have the acess right to adsminister users)
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu']['access callback'] = array('MODULE_check_menus_access');
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu']['access arguments'] = array(4, 'administer menu');
    //edit
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu/edit']['access callback'] = array('MODULE_check_menus_access');
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu/edit']['access arguments'] = array(4, 'administer menu');
    //add
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu/add']['access callback'] = array('MODULE_check_menus_access');
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu/add']['access arguments'] = array(4, 'administer menu');
}

function MODULE_check_menus_access($menu, $permission){
    global $user;
    $account = $user;

    if (user_access($permission, $account)) {
        if(array_key_exists ($menu['menu_name'], $menuList)){
            return user_access('can manage '.$menu['menu_name'], $account);
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function MODULE_permission() {
  return array(
    'can manage navigation' =>  array(
      'title' => t('Can manage navigation menu'),
      'description' => t('Limit access to the navigation menu'),
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: How can this be done in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Menu item visibility](https://drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility) module to hide the item for specific user role.

> This module exposes configurable and extendable visibility settings
>   for menu links. For example, if you want to create a 'My account' link
>   that points to /user, both anonymous and registered users have access
>   to the /user path, so both will see the link, even if anonymous users
>   do not technically have an account. Using this module will allow you
>   to only have your 'My account' link visible to registered users, and
>   hide it from anonymous users.

Comment: I think this module works only on the frontend side and not on the backend side(admin), but I found the solution to my problem, Thanks anyway

Comment: It also work for admin side. Only admin user can see all menu links. If you have found, then add your answer and accept that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
    function MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {

```
    //deny the menu if they are not admin (if they don't have the acess right to adsminister users)
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu']['access callback'] = array('MODULE_check_menus_access');
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu']['access arguments'] = array(4, 'administer menu');
    //edit
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu/edit']['access callback'] = array('MODULE_check_menus_access');
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu/edit']['access arguments'] = array(4, 'administer menu');
    //add
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu/add']['access callback'] = array('MODULE_check_menus_access');
    $items['admin/structure/menu/manage/%menu/add']['access arguments'] = array(4, 'administer menu');
}

function MODULE_check_menus_access($menu, $permission){
    global $user;
    $account = $user;

    if (user_access($permission, $account)) {
        if(array_key_exists ($menu['menu_name'], $menuList)){
            return user_access('can manage '.$menu['menu_name'], $account);
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function MODULE_permission() {
  return array(
    'can manage navigation' =>  array(
      'title' => t('Can manage navigation menu'),
      'description' => t('Limit access to the navigation menu'),
      ),
    );
}
```